# Unable to Connect to database in phpmyadmin through Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to connect to database of https://www.freesqldatabase.com but it's not connecting through given code.

But as I connect to my database through phpmyadmin it connects.

```
import mysql.connector    
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass',
                            host='host',
                            database='database',
                            port='3306')

try:
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
    select * FROM USERS
    """)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
finally:
    cnx.close()
```

Everytime I run this code I get these errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\kanwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 482, in open_connection
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(self.server_host,
File "C:\Users\kanwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "as.py", line 2, in <module>
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass',
File "C:\Users\kanwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kanwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\kanwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
File "C:\Users\kanwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
File "C:\Users\kanwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 500, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host:3306' (11001 getaddrinfo failed)
```

Comment: what error message are you getting please?

Comment: I have edited the code please check now @CEO

Comment: It looks like your user credentials and the database host and port are printed in your Traceback. If these are real, you should remove them.

Comment: Thanks I've changed .

Comment: mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",database="YourDatabase",password="yourPassword")                 

Please give me a feedback

Comment: Bro as I mentioned it's an online database, So I provided `python.connector.connect` the same credentials given by the website mentioned. When I enter the same credentials to phpmyadmin I get access to database.

Comment: What does `import socket; print(socket.gethostbyname_ex(host))` return?

Comment: `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed` @ogdenkev

Comment: Is `'host'` supposed to be a variable? Because now you're passing the literal address  `'host'` which doesn't resolve properly and is seen in your error message. Are you perhaps suppose to use `httpsfreesqldatabase.com` as the host?

Comment: Yes I had to hidden real values. This is dummy data.

Comment: do you run `phpmyadmin` on local computer? If you run on server then it may need different settings then external program.

Comment: I created account on this server and I can connect to database from my local computer (Linux) using settings from account's page https://www.freesqldatabase.com/account/ (not from `phpmyadmin`) - like `host='sql11.freesqldatabase.com'`, `database='sql11******'`, `user='sql11******'`, `password='yv********'`

Comment: Are you running your code behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I'm not using any proxy! Please tell me how to use proxy with python so I can access to my database.